# How to query multiple tables like this in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have some tables in my database like that.
The first one is DA table, which has three column and I want to query others table based on PROJECT_ID.

[image]

The next one is WORK table. I want to calculate SUM of work_bonus and work_salary by specific da_id.
[image]

The next table is the expense table

[image]

Next one is product table

[image]

The last one is the summary table. I want to print DA like below this table. That means suppose I want to search da based on project_id "15" so I will get two da_id from da table i.e da_id 1 and 2. Now work, expense and product table has da_id field. So I want to print DA summary from work, expense and product table. Here in WORK table DA_ID 1 has two records i.e work_id 1 and 3. I want to total its WORK_BONUS and WORK_SALARY value based on DA_ID that means total WORK_BONUS of DA_ID 1 will be 40 and WORK_SALARY of DA_ID 1 will be 400. Like this, rest table calculation will be same. Here is the final table which I want. So can you please help me to calculate the result in mysql? Thank you

[image]

Text version-

```
DA TABLE
-------------------------------------------------
|   DA_ID     |    PROJECT_ID  |      DA_DATE    |
-------------------------------------------------
|    1        |       15        |       8/7/18   |
-------------------------------------------------
|    2        |       15        |       4/7/18   |
-------------------------------------------------
|    3        |       14        |       6/7/18   |
-------------------------------------------------



WORK TABLE
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|   WORK_ID   |     DA_ID      |    WORK_BONUS  |      WORK_SALARY   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1        |       1        |       10       |           100      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2        |       2        |       20       |          200       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|    3        |       1        |       30       |          200       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------



EXPENSE TABLE
-----------------------------------------------------
|   EXP_ID    |    DA_ID        |      EXP_TOTAL    |
-----------------------------------------------------
|    1        |       1         |       10          |
-----------------------------------------------------
|    2        |       2         |       20          |
-----------------------------------------------------
|    3        |       1         |       30          |
-----------------------------------------------------



PRODUCT TABLE
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   PRODUCT_ID    |    DA_ID        |      PRODUCT_TOTAL    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|       1         |       1         |       5               |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|       2         |       2         |       10              |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|       3         |       1         |       15              |
-------------------------------------------------------------


SUMMARY TABLE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   SUMMARY_ID    |   DA_ID   |   TOTAL_BONUS  |   TOTAL_EXPENSE   |   TOTAL_PRODUCT   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       1         |     1     |        40      |        400        |         20        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       2         |     2     |        20      |        200        |         10        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Posting data as text means we can copy it for use. Posting as images means we have to type - some (eg me) are discouraged from answering purely because of this.

Comment: I am really Sorry i thought it would help someone to understand.

Comment: I don't see what's different about this problem from any other relational query in sql.

Comment: Why does your summary table show a DA_ID of 3 if you're querying by project_id 15? And where are you getting data for it when the tables only show for DA_ID 1 and 2? Otherwise you'd need a JOIN of some sort, probably a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Sorry for typing mistake.

Comment: The solution is, you need to learn SQL. There does not seem to be any issue. Could you please provide, what did you try to select the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achive this using query. There may be more appropriate way

## Way 1

```
SELECT D.DA_ID,
    (SELECT SUM(WORK_BONUS) FROM `WORK` W WHERE W.DA_ID = D.DA_ID) as TOTAL_BONUS,
    (SELECT SUM(WORK_SALARY) FROM `WORK` W WHERE W.DA_ID = D.DA_ID) as TOTAL_SALARY,
    (SELECT SUM(EXP_TOTAL) FROM EXPENSE E WHERE E.DA_ID = D.DA_ID) as TOTAL_EXPENSE,
    (SELECT SUM(PRODUCT_TOTAL) FROM PRODUCT P WHERE P.DA_ID = D.DA_ID) as TOTAL_PRODUCT
FROM DA as D left join WORK as W on D.DA_ID = W.DA_ID
WHERE D.PROJECT_ID = 15
GROUP BY D.DA_ID;
```

## Way 2

```
SELECT D.DA_ID, SUM(WORK_BONUS) as TOTAL_BONUS, SUM(WORK_SALARY) as TOTAL_SALARY, 
    (SELECT SUM(EXP_TOTAL) FROM EXPENSE E WHERE E.DA_ID = D.DA_ID) as TOTAL_EXPENSE,
    (SELECT SUM(PRODUCT_TOTAL) FROM PRODUCT P WHERE P.DA_ID = D.DA_ID) as TOTAL_PRODUCT
FROM DA as D left join WORK as W on D.DA_ID = W.DA_ID
WHERE D.PROJECT_ID = 15
GROUP BY D.DA_ID;
```

Comment: @Ashis Biswas: if this answer is useful, you can also upvote it (in addition to check it as the accepted answer) please also read: [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 1):

This query will help you:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT sum(WORK_BONUS) AS TOTAL_BONUS, 
           sum(WORK_SALARY) AS TOTAL_SALARY 
    FROM WORK WHERE DA_ID = ?)
) t1,
(
    SELECT sum(EXP_TOTAL) as TOTAL_EXPENSE 
    FROM EXPENSE WHERE DA_ID = ?
) t2, 
(
    SELECT sum(PRODUCT_TOTAL) AS TOTAL_PRODUCT 
    FROM PRODUCT WHERE DA_ID = ?
);
```